# Relation on @PrimaryColumn having also @PrimaryGeneratedColumn not involved

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using NestJS with Typeorm recipe and I am a newbie in both of them. We are migrating from Loopback3, where all of these were implemented with the basic features of the framework.

We have the following scenario for a lot of relations among our entities:

- Entity A with "id" and "code" fields, both of them are primary, but only "id" is auto-generated, "code" comes from other logics and it is always guaranteed to be unique.
- Entity B with "a_code" field that is a foreign key for entity A.

We have in class A:

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  code: string;

  @OneToMany(() => B, (b: B) => b.a_code)
  a_list: A[];
```

With controller:

```
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: A
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      a_list: {
        eager: true,
      },
      'a.a_list': {
        eager: true,
        alias: 'a_list',
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And for class B:

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  a_code: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => A, a => a.a_list) a: A;
```

For legacy reasons we need to keep both of these fields because these objects can be frequently removed and reinserted (changing the id in the meantime) leaving the relations "pending" with no impact on the business logic we have.

I noticed that syncing the database, what it's created, is of course an index in the format of (id, code), but the same is for the foreign key B=>A, that's not what I look for.
It's ok for me to have a generated primary key (id) and a unique field (code) to have the relation on the latter.

What I am trying to figure out is the best way to do this in Typeorm, and if there is a legit way to do it.

Comment: if i understand correctly, in class B, you want the a_code to be unique along with the id instead of being a foreign key to entity A ?

Comment: @adamC yes, I added the "unique: true" option into the column decorator for the code, but I can't get the correct behavior in the app, for example, it seems the code is not exposed in the api responses even using the ad-hoc decorator, maybe I keep omitting something necessary

Comment: please try @Unique(<constraint name>, ['id', 'a_code']) decorator on the entity class itself and not on a specific column. this will keep 'id' as the primary key and make the a_code unique for each id